# What are the modifications that we need to make while migrating a file writing C code from IDE to LoadRunner?

Tags: c, loadrunner

The below code works fine in Codeblocks IDE. When I paste it in action() in LoadRunner it gives the following compilation errors:

> Action.c (7): undeclared identifier FILE'
>
> Action.c (7): undeclared identifier fptr' d:\bits\heyo\\
>
> combined_heyo.c (5): 2 errors, not writing pre_cci.ci

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    char c[1000] = {"abcd"}; //Initialize a character array
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("c:\\program.txt","w");
    if(fptr==NULL){
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(fptr,"%s",c);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the compilation errors?

Comment: It is a good idea to edit your original post to include all the errors returned (the actual errors). That way it'll be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: `#include "stdio.h"` should be `#include <stdio.h>` although that shouldn't be the reason for your errors.

Comment: Action.c (7): undeclared identifier `FILE'
Action.c (7): undeclared identifier `fptr'
d:\\bits\\heyo\\\\combined_heyo.c (5): 2 errors, not writing pre_cci.ci

Comment: Improved grammar and capitalization, moved error messages from OP's comment into body of the question, formatted error messages, harmonized code indentation, removed unneeded blank lines in code.

Comment: Thank you :) :) @RobertColumbia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really bad idea to write a file from your virtual user under load.  Not only will it be this user, but all users running this same virtual user.  You will have massive contention for the write head access from tens/dozens/hundreds of users.   This also will turn the local file system into a bottleneck for your load generator.

Consider placing the data you write in an external service based repository, such as a queue, where you can pull it from if needed.   The most common desire leading to writing data out during a test is to pass the data to another user.  If this is your desire, then please consider RabbitMQ or similar

Comment: Thank you so much @James Pulley

Comment: I was unable to +1 this post since i have a reputation of less than 15, hence, i would request anyone who finds this answer valuable to +1 it thanks..

Comment: It should be noted that I prefer RabbitMQ to VTS becuase of its native support of a Web interface.  This works really well with web virtual users.

Comment: are there any quick guides in your knowledge which can illustrate the process of rabbitmq and loadrunner integration?

Comment: Use the management add in to RabbitMQ and the curl examples.   You can set the proxy in curl to the LoadRunner recording proxy to grab the output if needed, or simply place it in a web_url() statement in LoadRunner.  You will need to correlate for the return data set when you "Pop" from the queue.    Once you see the curl statements on the RabbitMQ management add-in page it should be straightforward.    I do setup the queues in advance and sometimes preload if I have a generated data set to use

Answer (score 0):

```
/*my mistake was that i used FILE instead of long, this is because the structure file is included in "stdio.h" file which cant be included by typing # include statement in loadrunner , this was caught when i saw th function reference for fprintf() in loadrunner help. Although this code works but should be avoided running with multiple users (see james pulley answer for more details)*/

/*corrected code*/




vuser_init()
{
char *filename = "c:\\helloworld.txt";
char c[1000] = {"abcd"};

long file;

   file=fopen(filename,"w");



   fprintf(file,"%s",c);

   fclose(file);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: My mistake was that i used FILE instead of long, this is because the structure file is included in "stdio.h" file which cant be included by typing # include statement in loadrunner , this was caught when i saw th function reference for fprintf() in loadrunner help. Although this code works but should be avoided running with multiple users (see james pulley answer for more details)*